# Runtime error exception Codewars attempt error

Tags: python, runtime

my code in running this kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ce399e0047a45001c853c2b/train/python

it passes basic tests but runtime error exception 12k ms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St8Sp.png)

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    # your code
    cat = []
    for i in range(0,len(ls)+1):
        cat.append(sum(ls[i:]))
    return cat
```

i tried a while True loop it was slower what do i do with this bro is it the server ? what can i do

the code was supposed to add each sum of an array or sub array? or like for example:

[1,2,3,4,5]
this should print out :
[15,14,12,9,4] i guess?

anyways here the site description:
Let us consider this example (array written in general format):

```
ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Its following parts:

```
ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [3, 6, 10]
ls = [6, 10]
ls = [10]
ls = []
The corresponding sums are (put together in a list): [20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]
```

The function parts_sums (or its variants in other languages) will take as parameter a list ls and return a list of the sums of its parts as defined above.

Other Examples:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
parts_sums(ls) -> [21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 0]
```

Notes
Take a look at performance: some lists have thousands of elements.
Please ask before translating.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `sum()` each time through the loop is O(n^2). Just calculate the total once, then subtract each element from the total to get the sum of the remaining elements.

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    total = sum(ls)
    cat = [total]
    for i in ls:
        total -= i
        cat.append(total)
    return cat
```